# pandas.apply expand column ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply, multi-index

I want to apply a function to a DataFrame that returns several columns for each column in the original dataset. The apply function returns a DataFrame with columns and indexes but it still raises the error ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.

I've tried to set the name of the output dataframe, to set the columns as a multiindex and set the index as a multiindex but it doesn't work.

Example: I have this input dataframe

```
df_all_users = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3],
    ],
    index=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"],
    columns=["user_1", "user_2", "user_3"])

          user_1  user_2    user_3
2020-01-01     1       2         3
2020-01-02     1       2         3
2020-01-03     1       2         3
```

The apply_function is like this:

```
def apply_function(df):
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    # these columns are in reality computed used some other functions
    df_out["column_1"] = df.values  # example: pyod.ocsvm.OCSVM.fit_predict(df.values) 
    df_out["column_2"] = - df.values  # example: pyod.knn.KNN.fit_predict(df.values)
    
    # these are the things I've tried without working
    df_out.name = df.name
    df_out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(df.name, column) for column in df_out.columns],
                                               names=["user", "score"])
    df_out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(df.name, idx) for idx in df_out.index],
                                             names=["user", "date"])
    print(df_out)
    return df_out

df_all_users.apply(apply_function, axis=0, result_type="expand")
```

Which raises the error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

The output that I expect would be like this:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
     [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
     [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    ],
    index=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(user, column)
                                       for user in ["user_1", "user_2", "user_3"]
                                       for column in ["column_1", "column_2"]],
                                      names=("user", "score"))
)

             user_1           user_2            user_3
           column_1 column_2 column_1 column_2 column_1 column_2
2020-01-01        1        1        2        2        3        3
2020-01-02        1        1        2        2        3        3
2020-01-03        1        1        2        2        3        3
```

Comment: How many columns should your output have? 6 + index? your first row only have 3 columns.

Comment: The output should have 6 columns, yes. I want to go from 3 in input to 6 in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was to transform output to a series of arrays, then concatenate the results:

```
import pandas as pd
df_all_users = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3],
    ],
    index=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"],
    columns=["user_1", "user_2", "user_3"])

def apply_function(df):
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    df_out["column_1"] = df.values
    df_out["column_2"] = df.values

    df_out = pd.Series([values for values in df_out.values], index=df.index)
    df_out.name = df.name
    return df_out

df_out = df_all_users.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(apply_function)
df_out = pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate(values, axis=0) for values in df_out.values],
                      index=df_out.index,
                      columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(user, column)
                                                         for column in ["column_1", "column_2"]
                                                         for user in df_out.columns
                                                        ], names=["user", "algorithm"]))
df_out



user          user_1                  user_2                  user_3
algorithm   column_1    column_2    column_1    column_2    column_1    column_2
2020-01-01         1           1           2           2           3           3
2020-01-02         1           1           2           2           3           3
2020-01-03         1           1           2           2           3           3
```

Comment: So, does this mean that we cannot return `pd.DataFrame` object to `apply` call?  Do you need the last line or can you get the same outcome with `broadcast` option in `apply` call? Thank you

Comment: In most cases, no, you cannot return a  `pd.DataFrame` . You can do something like `df_all_users.apply(lambda df: -df)` but not much more. Can you provide an example on using `broadcast` feature? I can only get `ValueError: too many dims to broadcast`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import numpy as np

df_all_users[np.repeat(df_all_users.columns.values,2)]
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify my intent: I don't want to replicate data but to apply different functions to the data of a user, each returning function returning a different column, I edited the description to show this